# Screen randomly gets almost black on Ubuntu 22.04 - 3 to 4 times a day

Tags: 22.04, screen, backlight

For quite a month now, I have the issue that my notebook screen randomly gets almost black. By almost I mean the content is still visible but hard to see. It seems like the backlight of the panel is switched off.
My current workaround is to change the resolution back and forth because this recovers the backlight of the panel. Changing the brightness via hotkeys doesn't change anything.

This is the hardware:

- ThinkPad T14s Gen3
- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- kernel: 6.2.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Oct 6 10:23:26 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- graphics: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt [Radeon 680M] (rev d1)

I already checked the common logs (kern.log, dmesg etc.) but didn't find anything promising. Also searched for known bugs regarding this. I hope it's not a hardware issue.

I appreciate any ideas for further investigation. Thx!